# dicordjs string manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if(msg.content.includes("[mid]")) {
   let str = msg.content
     let pokeID = str.substring(
       str.indexOf("[mid]") + 5,
       str.lastIndexOf("[/mid") //get the unique-code for a pokemon 

     );
     msg.channel.send({ content: `Here is your Pokemon:`, embeds: [midData(pokeID)] });
```

this code works fine, I'm would to be able to put in any user text that is before or after the [mid]code[/mid]

example user inputs "this text can be of any length or even null [mid]unique-code[/mid] this text can also be of any text or null"

the output should be :

this text can be of any length or even null this text can also be of any text or null

[mid]unique-code[/mid] (which is a link)

I have tried this: https://imgur.com/a/uq8CVpn  //image of output

I need 3 strings from the user input.

string1 = all text, if any before [mid]unique-code[/mid] // pokemon code

string2 = [mid]unique-code[/mid]

string3 = all text if any behind [mid]unique-code[/mid] //pokemon code

using node v16 and discord v13

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) like this (I also assumed you meant after and not behind in string3) :

also for clarification substring works like this:

```js
substring(startIndex, endIndex /*defaults to the end of the string if not specified*/ )
```

```js
const message = "this text can be of any length or even null [mid]unique-code[/mid] this text can also be of any text or null"

const beforeCode = message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf("[mid]")).trim()
const afterCode = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf("[/mid]") + 6).trim()

const code = message.substring(
    message.lastIndexOf("[mid]") + 5, 
    message.lastIndexOf("[/mid]")
).trim();

console.log("beforeCode:", beforeCode, "\nafterCode:", afterCode, "\ncode:", code)
```

- to get the text before the unique code we substring the message from `index 0 (the message's start) -> start index of "[mid]"`
- to get the text after the unique code we substring the message from `end index of "[mid/]" -> end of the string`
- to get the unique code we substring the message from `end index of "[mid]" -> start index of [mid/]`
- I also use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove any spaces from the start or end of the string

Comment: very close im not able to get afterCode to display in my output though. 
```if(msg.content.includes("[mid]")) {
    let str = msg.content
    let beforeCode = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("[mid]")).trim()
    let afterCode = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("[/mid]") +6).trim()
      let pokeID = str.substring(
        str.indexOf("[mid]") + 5,
        str.lastIndexOf("[/mid")

      );
      msg.channel.send({ content: beforeCode, afterCode, embeds: [midData(pokeID)] });  
  }```
this is my current code... working great except not displaying afterCode in reply

Comment: i got it ```if(msg.content.includes("[mid]")) {
    let str = msg.content
    let beforeCode = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("[mid]")).trim()
    let afterCode = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("[/mid]") +6).trim()
    let userText = beforeCode.concat(" ", afterCode)
    let pokeID = str.substring(
        str.indexOf("[mid]") + 5,
        str.lastIndexOf("[/mid")
      
      );
      msg.channel.send({ content: userText, embeds: [midData(pokeID)] });  
  }```